# Relational algebera without aggregate functions

Tags: sql, relational-database, aggregate-functions, relational-algebra

The table `WORKING` has the names of students and projects.

The values are:

```
(s1,p2)
(s1,p3)
(s1,p4)
(s2,p3)
(s2,p4)
(s3,p1)
(s4,p1)
(s3,p2)
(s4,p2)
(s5,p3)
(s5,p4)
(s6,p3)
```

I have to find the pair of students who worked in at least two different projects together.

I tried this query.

```
select w1.student, w2.student
from working w1,
     working w2
where w1.project != w2.project
  and w1.student != w2.student 
except (select w1.student, w2.student
        from working w1,
             working w2 
        where w1.project = w2.project
          and w1.student != w2.student);
```

But it's not working. Please help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: is it your homework?

Comment: Algebra, or SQL? If algebra, what version? (There are different ones.) Why are you giving sql? Which SQL? Does it offer EXCEPT or MINUS? Does it offer NATURAL JOIN? What does "it's not working" mean? Did it run? compile? What was the input? What did it do? Please read about asking questions on the help page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct R1.st1, R1.st2
FROM
    (SELECT w1.student st1, w2.student st2, w1.project pr
     FROM working w1, working w2
     WHERE w1.project = w2.project
     AND w1.student < w2.student) as R1,
    (SELECT w1.student st1, w2.student st2, w1.project pr
     FROM working w1, working w2
     WHERE w1.project = w2.project
     AND w1.student < w2.student) as R2
WHERE R1.st1 = R2.st1
AND R1.st2 = R2.st2
AND R1.pr <> R2.pr;
```

Basically, there are two identical subqueries here R1, R2. Each subquery list all pairs of students who have ever worked together, with the project(s) they worked on, with one row per project, so it would have:

```
s1, s2, p3
s1, s2, p4
s1, s3, p2
s1, s4, p2
s1, s5, p3
s1, s5, p4
s1, s6, p3
s2, s5, p3
s2, s5, p4
s2, s6, p3
s3, s4, p1
s3, s4, p2
s5, s6, p3
```

So, the result of R1 is this list, and the result of R2 is an identical list. The main query joins these two lists such that the students are the same and the project is different. So if two students only worked together on one project (e.g. s1 and s3), it will not join with anything. If they worked on multiple projects (e.g. s1 and s2), then they will be in the final result.

And this is obtained using only relational algebra operators without aggregation :)